# Transforming a Flux into a Tree with Spring Webflux

Tags: java, reactive, webflux

We recently started to refactor our Spring WebMVC code to WebFlux, replacing RestTemplate's by WebClient.

From an external web server, we receive a flat list of objects (Product), each of which contains a reference to a parent object:

```
            webClient
                .get()
                .uri(productURI)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Product.class)
```

We now to transform this list of products into a tree-like structure, consisting of few root Products (as a list) and many child Products in a hierarchical structure beneath each root Product.

In the former code, transformation was easily done, as we ended up with the complete flat list, from which we created a new result list.

With reactive streams, I'm puzzled how to transform the original Flux of Products into a completely different structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple solutions available.

In case your data fits in memory, the response is not paginated and you want to keep the existing implementation, you can collect the `Flux<Product>` into a list and use the existing algorithm.

```
productFlux
.collectList()
.map(products -> buildTree(products))
```

In case you want to compute the tree structure more efficiently, e.g. because of loading data in paginated manner, the `reduce` operator would be the way to go.

```
productFlux
.reduce(new ProductTree(), (tree, nextProduct) -> tree.add(nextProduct))
```

Here the tree needs a method `add(nextProduct)` to construct the final tree in multiple steps.